# Abstract collection of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm creating an WPF application using the MVVM framework.

I've got several classes all inheriting from a base class "MessageParentBase"

```
public class ChatMessage : MessageParentBase
{
}

public class CargoMessage : MessageParentBase
{
}
```

The ViewModels all inherit once again from a base class "ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel"

```
public class UserControlChatViewModel : ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel
{
}

public class UserControlCargoViewModel : ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel
{
}
```

Now what I want to do is have an observable collection in my "ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel" class

```
abstract internal ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase> GridData
{
    get; set;
}
```

Which is there so I can have a generic method at the "ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel" level, but at the child classes I want to have a more specific collection declared

```
internal override ObservableCollection<ChatMessage > GridData
{
    get { return _GridData; }
    set
    {
        _GridData = value;
    }
}
```

Visual studio is telling me it must be declared as a type of "MessageParentBase".

Can someone please explain to me how I can achieve this as I'm struggling at the moment.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no need for a field (_GridData) if you use auto implemented properties   (get;set;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *ObservableCollection< ChatMessage>* isn't the same as *ObservableCollection< MessageParentBase>* so you can't override it.

You could use this like this:

```
public class MessageParentBase
{
}

public class ChatMessage : MessageParentBase
{
}

public abstract class ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel<T> where T : MessageParentBase
{
    abstract internal ObservableCollection<T> GridData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Child : ParentMessageWindowBaseViewModel<ChatMessage>
{

    internal override ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> GridData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

But storing all Childs in 1 list isn't possible. So it won't fix the issue with inheritance on a generic property.

Comment: Perfect, did exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for taking time out to help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you declare the *property* `GridData` to be **`abstract`**, why do you also introduce a backing *field* `_GridData` there? Don't do that.

If you want the property to be `abstract`, do not put any supporting field there. If you want to implement the property at the "high" level (base class), remove the `abstract` modifier from it.